# Data not rendering correctly using openstreet and d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js, openstreetmap

I'm trying to show locations in cardiff city with the json data on open street Google map with d3.js, in json data i have latitude and longitude, I'm using d3.js to show images on specific locations and use arcs to connect them. I want to create something like [this](https://gist.github.com/zverok/10990642) (I'm aware that it do not use d3 though, but i want to get the data points rendered in d3)

I'm using reference code from [here](https://c9.io/victorsc/d3js_google_maps)

What i tried so far is [here in plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/dOBYE55G4stUiysY7XXr/preview)

The issues Which I'm struggling with is:

1. When the Map is loaded with all the city data i.e in script.js on 10th line if you replace the code to use cardiff.json data, instead of cardiff1.json data the browser hangs.
   (cardiff1.json contains few data of city while cardiff.json contains all data of city around 1498 records)
2. I have used 700px X 400px div to display data and the viewport area for svg i have set as 99999 X 99999 . hence only points lying in (0,0) to (99999,99999) are shown i.e from point top,left to few distance on right hand side and bottom (you can drag the map to see) but the points on left side and top are not drawn as the svg lags in view port.
3. On zoom in and zoom out some location get cut and displayed partially.

Please help me in this or any suggestions, Thanks in Advance.